# How to delete a key/value pair from a struct in Coldfusion?

Tags: struct, coldfusion, key-value

(using Coldfusion8/MySQL5.0.88)

I'm storing JSON strings in a database. Strings consist of an `id` (key) and a number of `items` in a list (values).

Values look like this:

```
LOCAL.dropRecall = {"994323":"596895,596871,596864,596888,596840abc,596833,596826","991234":"9999,8888,abced"}
```

My problem is trying to delete a `key/value` pair. I'm trying like this:

```
<cfif  StructKeyExists(LOCAL.dropRecall,"#Session.id#")>
   <cfdump output="e:\dump.txt" label="catch" var="detected">
   <cfset StructDelete( LOCAL.dropRecall,"#Session.id#", "true")>
</cfif>
```

which correctly detects the key/value pair (`detected` is reported), but deleting it does not work.

**Question:**
What am I doing wrong? Why is the key/value pair not removed?

**EDIT**:
Ok. Found it. I queried the database for field `items`, set this to `LOCAL.dropRecall` and wrote `items` back into the database... so the `structDelete` worked, but I did not write the empty struct back to the database.

Comment: That looks good... Don't need the quotes or hashes though or the last argument to structdelete. If you dump local.droprecall after the structdelete what do you get?

Comment: The code works fine for me ie it deletes an *existing* key like `994323`. So what test are you using to determine that this "does not work"?

Comment: @Leigh: ah... 1sec. I think that is the problem.

Comment: @Leigh. THANKS! That check helped. Struct was cleared, but I did not write it back to the database... Make it an answer?

Comment: had a feeling it was something like that

Comment: To re-iterate Stuart's comment: `StructDelete( LOCAL.dropRecall , Session.id )` - does exactly the same thing, with less noise.

Comment: Yeah. I changed that, too... I copied it from [Coldfusion LiveDocs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/functions_s_19.html)

Comment: Unfortunately the LiveDocs code examples are often badly written.

Comment: @frequent - May as well accept one of the other answers, or post your own, as you figured it out yourself. Plus I do not really have anything profound to add, except get rid of the extra `#` signs. Oh wait someone already said that too :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check that the value of `session.id` is what you think it is (no extra whitespace or anything like that).  I tried a modification if your code on CF8, and it works fine for me:

```
<cfset variables.id = 991234>
<cfset LOCAL.dropRecall = deserializeJson('{"994323":"596895,596871,596864,596888,596840abc,596833,596826","991234":"9999,8888,abced"}')>
<cfset LOCAL.safeCopy = duplicate(LOCAL.dropRecall)> 

<cfif  StructKeyExists(LOCAL.dropRecall,"#variables.id#")>
    <cfset StructDelete( LOCAL.dropRecall,"#variables.id#", "true")>
</cfif>
<cfdump var="#LOCAL#">
```

Does that code *not* work for you?

Comment: No problem. Dumping the result still showed me what the problem was (me not updating the database with the correct value). Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if the problem is that your variable names inside `LOCAL.dropRecall` start with a number? ColdFusion variables should always begin with a letter, underscore, or Unicode currency symbol.

Comment: This hasn't really been true since CF5. Struct keys (which all variables are, these days) can have any name you like. It's only with dot-notation the old rules are still valid, but with associative array notation, anything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Updated version of Adam's solution for ColdFusion 2016

```
<cfscript>
   variables.id = 991234;
   LOCAL.dropRecall = deserializeJson('{"994323":"596895,596871,596864,596888,596840abc,596833,596826","991234":"9999,8888,abced"}');
   LOCAL.safeCopy = duplicate(LOCAL.dropRecall);

   LOCAL.dropRecall.delete(variables.id); // you don't have to test if it is there

   writedump(LOCAL);
</cfscript>
```